# Plotting robertson diagram/pd diagram using gnuplot

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I've to plot a robertson diagram and a pd diagram for division algorithms.
They look like something in the pictures shown at the end of this post.
I basically have a C++ programs that derive all the needed parameters so I just have to write down some kind of scripts that plots all these lines together.

Considering the PD diagram, this corresponds to having slopes `m[0],...,m[n-1]` and therefore plotting `y = m[0]*x,...,y = m[n-1]*x`  for some `x`  `[x0,x1]` . What's the fastest approach in order to achieve that? I was thinking about extending my C++ code to spit out some script file that can be executed by gnuplot, but I never used it so I don't know what should be the format or what I need in general.

Maybe it's something really silly, or maybe I just don't know what I actually need to do that.

[image: Robertson diagram][image: PD-diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your slope data is in a file with one value in every line, you can transform it to one string and then use as array. Data is converted with `tr` utility by replacing EOL characters to spaces. Then every value is used in the function `f(k,x)` in a range `[x1:x2]`.

Here is datafile:

```
$ cat rob.dat 
20
10
5
2
-2
-5
-10
-20
```

It is converted to: `20 10 5 2 -2 -5 -10 -20` and stored in a variable `a`.

With png terminal, you can get a picture, but without italic symbols:

```
set term pngcairo enh mono solid lw 1.5 font "Helvetica,14" size 600,800
set output "rob.png"
set nokey
set noborder
set noxtics
set noytics
x1=-0.1
x2=10.0
f(k,x)=(x>=x1 && x<=x2 ? k*x : 1/0)
a=system("tr '\\n' ' ' < rob.dat")
v(n)=word(a,n)
set style arrow 1 head size 0.2, 25 filled
set arrow from x1-1,0 to x2+1.,0 arrowstyle 1
set arrow from 0.,f(v(8),x2) to 0.,f(v(1),x2) arrowstyle 1
set arrow from 4.,100. to 7.,60. arrowstyle 1 front
set label "Selection interval\nfor {/:Italic q_{j+1} = k}" at 1.,120.
set label "{/:Italic U_a = r{/Symbol r}d}" at x2+0.1, f(v(1),x2)
set label "{/:Italic U_k}" at x2+0.1, f(v(2),x2)
set label "{/:Italic L_k}" at x2+0.1, f(v(3),x2)
set label "{/:Italic U_0}" at x2+0.1, f(v(4),x2)
set label "{/:Italic L_0}" at x2+0.1, f(v(5),x2)
set label "{/:Italic U_k}" at x2+0.1, f(v(6),x2)
set label "{/:Italic L_k}" at x2+0.1, f(v(7),x2)
set label "{/:Italic L_{-a} = -r{/Symbol r}d}" at x2+0.1, f(v(8),x2)
set label "{/Italic rw[j]}" at 0.3,f(v(1),x2)
set label "{/Italic k} < 0" at 2.,-130.
set style fill solid 0.3
plot [-2:12][] for [b in a] f(b,x) w l lw 2 lc rgb "black", "+" u 1:(f(v(2),$1)):(f(v(3),$1)) w filledcurves
```

[image]

Using postscript eps terminal, you can get ones (replace two first lines):

```
set term post eps enh mono solid lw 2 font "Helvetica,30" size 6 in,9 in
set output "rob.eps"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi I'm reading through your answer, what version of gnuplot are you using? I've the 4.0. Not sure whether or not your code would work for me as well.

Comment: My version is 4.6. Upgrade gnuplot because that's a pretty old version.